# Try to create stopper in my application

Tags: android, android-layout

i created running app and i trying to create stopper that starting when user press start button.
but when i using thread the application return black screen
,this is my onCreate method i added thread

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    SetTextOnView();

                }
            });
        }
    };
        t.start();
```

the SetTextOnView method contain

```
public void SetTextOnView()
{
  TextView  timedisp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stopperdisplay);
  while(true)
  {
    timedisp.setText(String.valueOf(total));
  }



}
```

the problem start when i add the while statment
why is that?

Comment: You do an infinite loop with some work in the main (=UI) thread. So the application start to not respond then display a black screen

Comment: so if i want to create stopper that Measures walk time of the user when he press start button how can i do that without while?

Comment: You need the while but not in the main thread and you need to add some delay between each setText.

Comment: i try to add while within the run method in the thread but it gives same result

Answer (score 1):

Do the loop in your thread to not block the ui thread + add some delay to not block the ui thread :

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    SetTextOnView();
                }
            });
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
};
```

And your SetTextOnView :

```
public void SetTextOnView()
{
    TextView  timedisp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stopperdisplay);
    timedisp.setText(String.valueOf(total));
}
```

Comment: thanks work perfect! :) i didnt know that i need to set delay inside the thread , so for my own understanding when i create thread i need to add delay for the reson that i dont want that thread to Disturb the main thread( i gess it is the thread that runs the oncreate method and so..) yes?

Comment: Yes, the main thread (= UI thread in Android) is the one who managed life cycle of activity, the display, the interface, etc... You need to free this thread as much as possible to have a reactive app. So, the loop and the delay are here to execute the setText only once per second to minimize the impact on the app.